# Can I disable an update panel programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a master page which has some user controls within an update panel.

I would like to put a property in this page to let the content pages to be able to enable/disable async postback way of working this page.

Can I achieve it programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can. set **EnablePartialRendering="false"** on the ScriptManager, it will in effect disable the AJAX behavior of the UpdatePanel.